# During Edit Mode, Circle selection goes wild

Tags: edit-mode

I encountered strange behavior of circle selection with Blender 2.79a...

[image: before selection]

I press C and try to select something, like left foot.

[image: Circle selection selected inside and outside of the circle]

When you take a close look at second screen shot, not only inside of circle but even outside, two from left knee, one from below the belly button, and several others also get selected. 
why??? How can I fix this strange behavior???

Comment: Can you try doing the same thing in ortho mode `Numpad 5` to toggle.

Comment: thx for advice! I pressed num5 but result is exact same, additional selections here and there.

Comment: The only other thing that seems to fix this for me is to do the selection in wireframe mode `z key` to toggle, but that is not ideal, when you don't want to select the stuff in the back.

Comment: thx again Rick! I didn't know wireframe mode and this is very useful! Regarding selection problem, I am installing 2.8 and will see how it goes...

Comment: After submitting Bug Report to Blender Dev Team, they hinted the graphic driver might not compatible with current version of Blender. So I downloaded little older driver from nVidia then works fine again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have contacted Blender Dev team and they suggested my graphic driver might cause of this problem. 
What I installed combination were:

Blender version : 2.79a &
GeForce Game Ready Driver version : 391.01

This combination was not good. I upgraded/downgraded Blender but selection problem won't disappear. Then I downgraded nVidia driver from 391.01 to 388.71. Then the problem has solved, back to normal behavior.

nVidia driver consists more than 10 components and looks like newer version of component(s) from 391.01 is still in my system. So, I am not sure which component was the reason of problem but downgrading graphic driver certainly help, if you encounter similar problems.